# Symfony2 and drag & drop function

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, drag-and-drop

I have a Symfony 2 project and in of of my views, I have a list of some authors.
What I would like is to give to the user the possibility to delete authors from the list and also change their places in th list

I know that this is possible with jquery but is there any Symfony2 built in function for that.

I have read about the draggable_element() helper for symfony 1 but there are not lot of thing about: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_0/en/11-Ajax-Integration#chapter_11_sub_drag_and_drop

Do you have an example on how could Imake this? Having a tutorial can be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably start with the cookbook article on [creating a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). You will probably need to create your own JavaScript for the drag/drop, however.

Also, check out [KNP Bundles](http://knpbundles.com/), a great listing of a bunch of Symfony bundles that might help with this or other features for your project.

Comment: Thank you MrGlass, but what's about the draggable_element() helper?

Comment: draggable_element was a form element available in symfony 1. Symfony 2 has an entirely new codebase & form system, as far as I know there is no draggable element provided by SensioLabs. Check KNP Bundles, someone may have made a plugin.

Comment: Thank you @MrGlass, a +1 for you.